# Is a question mark needed?

Tags: question-mark

Is a question mark needed after "kitchen"? I feel there might be as I imagine Bob has omitted "didn't you?" from the end of the sentence. If it was there a question mark seems like it would be needed: "Well, you saw the mess he made in the kitchen, didn't you?"

Bob: Tony's getting worse.

Rob: He is?

Bob. Well, you saw the mess he made in the kitchen? Now he's wrecked the bathroom too!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, the question mark is not necessary.

However, its presence does not make the sentence incorrect even if Bob knows that Rob had seen the mess. This is an example of a *rhetorical question*.

> A rhetorical question is a figure of speech in the form of a question that is asked to make a point rather than to elicit an answer. [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rhetorical_question)

Answer (score 1):

It depends on whether the sentence is intended to be a statement or a question (both are possible in your example). The punctuation should reflect the intent.

Comment: A statement I think as Bob expects Rob to know the answer, that's why he doesn't wait for a reply.

Comment: @Jack In that context, it's often a rhetorical question, meaning "Did you see ...?". Bob can still expect Rob to know the answer to a rhetorical question.